# is there a way to sort files in a directory by view count? Win 7

Tags: windows-7, sorting

As per the title, can files in a directory be sorted by view count in windows7 ? I have a folder with a lot of videos. I want to delete bottom 20 least viewed videos. This would require me to sort these files by view count

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to get out on a limb here and say that this is not possible. There is last modified attribute and, if enabled, there is a last accessed with NTFS in Windows 7. I can't think of anywhere that tells you 'You have watched this video 10 times' and I do a lot of photography and video work on my Win PC. Even checked my directory attribs (windows 8) and I don't see anything that tells me the view count (that would be cool!)

Of course you learn a new trick everyday =)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows NTFS file system can not do this, but metadata can, sort of.  Now-a-days most files have metadata that can, in some cases, contain user/program defined meta-data.  This include "view counts".  However, lets say program A handles this meta-data, but then you access the data with program B.  "Program A" maybe aware of the meta-data and update the view counts, but "program B" might not.  Therefore counts base only on this method may not be accurate.

From **Windows Explorer** switch to details view, and right click on any **column heading**. Select **more** and if your very lucky **view counts** may or may not be there.  If it is there check the box and click ok and it should be visible.

Left click on the **column heading** "view counts" and windows will resort it in order.

Comment: The great majority of column headings one can add in Explorer have no data associated with them. One needs to have an appropriate shell extension installed, and presumably also some program which collects and maintains the relevant data.

Comment: I was thinking of using the date accessed field in properties of a file.

Comment: You can easily sort by date accessed by displaying said field and clicking on the column heading.  See above and click on **more** and then **Date Accessed** and ok

Comment: I got to say. I have been using Windows since 3.1 and now running Windows 8.1. I can't remember ever seeing view counts. My Win 8.1 is NTFS & view counts is not in there.